# Tanimoto Coefficient in mhout return only 1.0 as prediction value

Tags: java, mahout, recommendation-engine, mahout-recommender, collaborative-filtering

I have tried to run mahout framework and  use Tanimoto coefficient on set of items. Fortunately, it works with me, however, it returns value 1.0 for all predicted items, the code was as follow:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

             DataModel model = new FileDataModel(new     File("stack.csv"));      //load data from file     needed for     computation
            UserSimilarity similarity = new         TanimotoCoefficientSimilarity(model); //log likelihood similarity will be     used         for making recommendation .
    /*To use TanimotoCoefficientSimilarity replace “LogLikelihoodSimilarity”         with TanimotoCoefficientSimilarity”.
    UserSimilarity implementation provides how similar two two users are     using     LoglikehoodSimilarity */
            UserNeighborhood neighborhood =  new NearestNUserNeighborhood(2,         similarity, model);  //Define a group of     user most similar to a given user . 2        define a group of 2 user having most similar preference

             Recommender recommender = new GenericUserBasedRecommender(      model,     neighborhood, similarity); // creates a     recommendation engine


             List<RecommendedItem>recommendations =      recommender.recommend(3, 5);
/*one recommendation for user with ID 4 . In Mahout it always take Integer         value i.e It will always take userId and     number of item to be recommended */

            for (RecommendedItem recommendation : recommendations) {
                System.out.println(recommendation);
            }

    }
```

The out put as follow:

```
[main] INFO org.apache.mahout.cf.taste.impl.model.file.FileDataModel - Creating FileDataModel for file stack.csv
[main] INFO org.apache.mahout.cf.taste.impl.model.file.FileDataModel - Reading file info...
[main] INFO org.apache.mahout.cf.taste.impl.model.file.FileDataModel - Read lines: 696
RecommendedItem[item:589, value:1.0]
RecommendedItem[item:380, value:1.0]
RecommendedItem[item:2916, value:1.0]
RecommendedItem[item:3107, value:1.0]
RecommendedItem[item:2028, value:1.0]

Part of my data file is as follow:

    1   3408
    1   595
    1   2398
    1   2918
    1   2791
    1   2687
    1   3105
      .
      .
      .
```

Up to my best knowledge that Tanimoto Coefficient value is usually between 0 and 1.0 , but here it shows only 1.0 which is something impossible as I think. So, anybody have any idea how can solve this problem? is there any threshold that I can change?

Any help with this is highly appreciated.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Tanimoto coefficient, or also known as the Jaccard coefficient, completely ignores preference values and just considers that the user likes this items, and nothing more. How it is computed? The final value is the number of items that two users express some preference for (in other words only like) divided by the number of items that either user expresses some preference for.

Read more about Jaccard coefficient here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jaccard_index

Read more about the Mahout's implementation `TanimotoCoefficientSimilarity` in the book [Mahout in Action](http://manning.com/owen/).

Comment: Thank you @Dragan Milcevski for your reply. I have read http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jaccard_index before, but in case of I always get 1 for predicted preferences value, so I can't decide in my example above which item 589 or 380 is more likely to be prefered by user number 5 and all items will have same priority to the user, where I'm not sure if this correct. Based on http://academypublisher.com/proc/wisa09/papers/wisa09p29.pdf the value of Tanimoto coefficient the value of prediction is not usually 1.0 it can be less than this value, since it start from 0 to 1.0 . Thank you very much.

Comment: Yes you are right. I will edit my answer. However I guess you have lots of similar ones. Try getting the top 100 recommendations and see if the the values change.

Comment: Thank you very much @Dragan Milcevski for your advice. I have tried it with the top 100 recommendations and tried to change the number of similar items from 2 to 5 and 10. But, unfortunately still getting prediction value 1.0 . I do not know why :(

Comment: I can only assume that you have lots of similar users. Try with higher numbers, i.e. 1000 and 50 for produced recommendations and NN.